# What does the boundary of convex hulls look like in matrix Lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, convex-polytopes, geodesics

Let $G$ be a compact matrix Lie group under the Killing form metric $\langle \xi, \eta \rangle_g = -\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}((g^{-1}\xi)^T(g^{-1}\eta))$ for $g \in G$ and $\xi,\eta \in T_gG$. Let $C \subset G$ be a geodesically convex set. Pick finitely many $g_1,...,g_N \in C$ and define $\Omega$ to be the smallest closed convex set containing those points. What does the boundary of $\Omega$ look like? Is it like the smallest geodesic polygon that fits those points, like in Euclidean space? Or is it something more complicated?

Comment: What are $M$ and $C$?  (Did you mean $M \subset G$ instead of $G \subset M$?)

Comment: Maybe meant $C\subseteq G$.

Comment: @LSpice Apologies. I meant $C \subset G$. I edited my question.

Comment: You did not specify the metric on $G$. Are you assuming that $G$ is compact and endowing it with the Killing metric ? In that case, $G$ is not uniquely geodesic, so convex hulls are not a very robust notion (and it is not even clearly defined globally).

Comment: Perhaps a first case to look at is $SU(2) = S^3$. How do you define convex hulls in a sphere ?

Comment: @NicolasTholozan I updated the question. Let's say $G$ is compact and equipped with the killing metric. Although $G$ is not uniquely geodesic, I am assuming the points I defined are already within a convex set, and hence convex hulls are well-defined. Can you elaborate what you mean by them not being very robust?

Comment: @NicolasTholozan By convex set, I mean for any 2 points in the set, there exists a unique minimizing geodesic connecting those points. The convex hull of a set is the smallest convex set that contains that set. I'm in particular looking at the closed convex hull (I am unsure if convex hulls are necessarily closed in non-Euclidean spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted to say *smallest geodesic polytope* (not *polygon*).

It is unclear what is polytope in a the matrix Lie group, but it seems to require geodesic hypersurfaces.
They do not exist in most Riemannian manifold starting from dimension 3 and matrix Lie groups are not exceptional.

BTW, if you are interested in convex sets in general Riemannian manifolds,
then check our paper ["About every convex set..."](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15189).

Comment: Thank you. Would you by any chance know the definition for a "generic manifold". It does not appear in that paper.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler It does:  Given a positive integer $k$, we say that a property $P$ holds for $C^k$-generic Riemannian metric $g$ on a manifold $M$ if the property $P$ holds for a dense G-delta set (that is, a countable intersection of open subsets) of metric tensors in the $C^k$-topology.

Comment: I'm confused by that sentence. That seems to describe a generic property, not a generic Riemannian manifold. Could you provide a non-Euclidean example of a generic manifold? Is, say, a matrix Lie group equipped with the sub-euclidean structure generic?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler, You can do it, but I what for? For example, let us assume that "property" is something that can be expressed in a finite number of words; so there are only countable set of properties. Then say that manifold $M$ is generic if any generic property holds for $M$. But in this case any manifold that can be completely described in finite number of words is not generic, so it is not possible to describe it explicitly despite most of manifolds are generic.

Comment: So you're saying that generic manifolds are non-constructible?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Actually more. But concerning your question --- the manifolds without geodesic hypersurfaces include generic manifolds, but they include many vary simple manifolds as well. The same thing for the statements in our paper --- from the proof you can get quite explicit property that guarantees such behavior of convex sets --- the curvature should not meet certain identities.

Comment: Thank you for the information!